# Database update from AsyncTask onPostExecute

Tags: android, database, android-asynctask

I have a class which I use to send stats from my application to a website.  There are multiple methods catering for different types of data I want to send, code extract here:

```
public class TransmitMetrics {
private final String request = "http://192.168.0.60/post.php";
private String function;
private URL url;
private HttpURLConnection connection;
private String line;
private String urlParameters;

public void updatePhone(String device_id, String country) {

    String make = Build.MANUFACTURER;
    String model = Build.MODEL;
    String sdk = Build.VERSION.SDK;

    function = "phoneupdate";
    urlParameters = "function=" + function + "&device_id=" + device_id
            + "&make=" + make + "&model=" + model + "&country=" + country
            + "&sdk=" + sdk;

    new sendData().execute();
}
```

I then have a nested AsyncTask class (sendData) which deals with the HTTPURLConnection stuff which can't be run on the mainUI thread, part of the code here:

```
private class sendData extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Integer> {
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Integer result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
                   //Proposed DB stuff here based on return code
                   //stored in the result variable.
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {

        try {
            url = new URL(request);
        } catch (MalformedURLException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }

        try {
            connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            connection.setDoOutput(true);
            connection.setDoInput(true);
            connection.setInstanceFollowRedirects(false);
            connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
            connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type",
                    "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
            connection.setRequestProperty("charset", "utf-8");
            connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Length",
                    "" + Integer.toString(urlParameters.getBytes().length));
            connection.setUseCaches(false);

            DataOutputStream wr = new DataOutputStream(
                    connection.getOutputStream());
            wr.writeBytes(urlParameters);
            wr.flush();
```

I've no issues with the code, it works fine, however, I've recently been trying to improve the application by adding a database update dependent on the response code returned from the HttpURLConnection.
onPostExecute() is the standard way, but I'm not sure if I should start declaring a database connection and performing db updates from within the onPostExecute() method.

I'd like some advice if there is a better way to do it, or if I shouldn't be using an AsyncTask in the first place for this type of functionality.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a first note I believe you should have a separate class to perform DB operation as your code would be too complicated for a class. It already seems to break the [Single-Responsibility Principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle). I would move the current Http operations to a new class. Also, it's not safe to keep a class reference to URL, HttpURLConnection and parameters as you might have 2 running requests in the same time and sharing these attributes would lead to unexpected results.

Back to your question, assuming `sendData.execute(...)` was started on UI thread, then onPostExecute(Integer) will run on UI thread as well. The DB operation should be performed on a non-UI thread since you don't know how big your database will grow "in the wild". So you could move the DB operation on another AsyncTask - if you need the DB operation result. Otherwise a simple background thread is more than enough.

Comment: Thanks, that makes more sense, I was planning to move the HTTP bits out to a new class, but the only problem I have is that the Async task doesn't give you much flexibility in the onPostExecute() method as its really only for UI updates.  If I had a separate class for HTTP and DB operations, would I be able to call the DB class from the onPostExecute() method with a valid context?

Comment: *Async task doesn't give you much flexibility in the onPostExecute() method as its really only for UI updates* You can return a custom object in method onPostExecute() and there you have the flexibility. You could make a custom `HttpResponseObject` class with response code, failure details and whatever you need. That can be returned and evaluated on UI thread if you need extra flexibility. Would that be flexible enough?

Comment: *If I had a separate class for HTTP and DB operations, would I be able to call the DB class from the onPostExecute() method with a valid context?* Yes, you could do that. *Would I be better using a Handler/Thread class instead?* Handler is used for sending a message to the thread that created the handler, while a thread is a thread. Any mechanism you use is OK, just as long you don't block the UI thread.

Answer (score 0):

yes u can use the responsebody from the httpurlconnection. i think u r not using json in sending or receiving the data from the server. better to use json format which helps in getting data in an object form or as an array from the server side.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Aynctask to perform any task that performs some other operation and you want result of that operation on UI .Lets take your example , you can use asyntask to do some database and cursor operation in onBackground method and update data in onPostExecute method , same rules can be applied to any Non UI operation.

Comment: Hmm, that leads me onto another query then about getting the "context" through to the onPostExecute(), I'd need to pass it to the top level class TransmitMetrics and then from there pass it again to the nested sendData class so that I could use the database connection in the onPostExecute() method.  Seems a bit ugly to me?  is there a better way of doing this?

Comment: You can make setter getter methods in your class  TransmitMetrics and pass it in sendData asynctask via constructor .Make a default constructor in sendData class.

like "new sendData(context).execute()"